# How do I insert/update date into my DB? I used Python 3, SQLAlchemy, multiprocessing. Connection not available

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, connection, multiprocessing

My Python module is used multiprocessing.

But my module is printing an error message:

> OperationalError(“MySQL Connection not available.”) OperationalError:
>   MySQL Connection not available

A similar phenomenon occurs regardless of the type of DB.

And only the first update or insert is carried out and does not operate after that.

- utils/database.py

  ```
  class DataBase:
      engine = create_engine('db connect info')
      db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
      Base = declarative_base()
      Base.query = db_session.query_property()
      conn = engine.connect()

      def init_db(self):
          import models
          self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
  ```
- check_id_module.py

  ```
  from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

  ...

  def update_status(checkpoint2_list):
      DB.db_session.query(Mymodel). \
          filter(Mymodel.username.in_(checkpoint2_list)). \
          update({Mymodel.status: 'test'},
                 synchronize_session=False)
      DB.db_session.commit()
      DB.db_session.close()


  def check_user(queue):
      checkpoint2_list = []
      while True:
          if queue.empty():
              break
          username = queue.get()
          api_url = 'request url'.format(username)
          res = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
          if res.status_code == 404:
              print(username, res.status_code)
              checkpoint2_list.append(username)
      if checkpoint2_list:
          update_status(checkpoint2_list)


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      procs = []
      starttime = datetime.now()
      accounts_queue = Queue()
      accounts = DB.db_session.query(Mymodel.username).filter(
          Mymodel.status.in_(['run', 'run2'])
      )

      insert_queue(accounts_queue, accounts)

      for i in range(20):
          proc = Process(target=check_user, args=(accounts_queue,))
          procs.append(proc)
          proc.start()

      for proc in procs:
          proc.join()

      accounts_queue.close()

      endtime = datetime.now()
      print('\nRunning Time : ', endtime - starttime)
  ```

Where in my source code is a multiprocessing connection error occurring?

Comment: Have you checked how many connections are open for mysql?

Comment: All the connection related errors occur regardless of the database, including mysql, postgres ., sqlite, and sqlite.